# DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey attribute doesn't map value to the field

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have this model:

```
public class Company
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("PK")]
    public string Id { get;set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey("SK")]
    public string Type { get;set; }

    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey("GSI1")]
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Index called GSI1 and its partition key is Type (column name is "SK") and its sort key is field with name "GSI1SK".

I assume that if I insert instance of this model using `DynamoDbContext` it will create item with these attributes:

[image]

But as a result field `GSI1SK` is empty.
So how does this `DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey` attribute works?
Looks like to populate `GSI1SK` field I need to create one more field in my model and populate it manually. What is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

There is some discrepancy between what you describe in text and your code.

On the one hand you write

> and its sort key is field with name "GSI1SK".

Where, on the other hand, your code specifies the name of that field to be `GSI1`:

```
[DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey("GSI1")]
```

IIUC you want to have a single field which has one name in the index and a different name in the table. This is not how code that interacts with DDB usually works (and, in fact, I am not sure it is even supported). Usually, there is a single name for a field and you use the same name both in when accessing the item through a table as well as when accessing that item through a GSI.

Comment: GSI1 is the indexName that is first argument of the constructor

Comment: @StNickolas:  My bad. So, what is the GSI1SK attribute?

Comment: GSI1SK it is separate attribute for index, I don't want to put any meaning on it so I can push any data for that specific index, but also I want the same value be in meaningful attribute. Like above I want GSI1SK save company name, so when i use queries I just sort by this name. For other items this attribute can contain different values, e.g dates or sort order and so on